# Why doesn't stringstream consume output during hex formatting?

Tags: c++

Here is a minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;
    unsigned int output;
    
    ss << "0xBB";
    ss >> std::hex >> output;
    std::cout << output << std::endl;
    
    ss << "0xAA";
    ss >> std::hex >> output;
    std::cout << output;
}
```

I would expect final output to have decimal value of `0xAA`, however 2 187 (`0xBB`) are printed instead. What is the problem here? Shouldn't stringstream "consume" (move stream pointer) after reading the data?

I expect to have 2 outputs: `0xBB` and `0xAA` (in decimal format)

Comment: you can do the same without hex to see the same effect https://godbolt.org/z/5bzEsxTrv

Comment: What do you mean stream isn't reset? Check out this official cpp reference for operator `>>` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

In their example, stream moves in expected way and `n` `f` `b` are all filled (alongside cout rdbuf)
@kiner_shah

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number thank you! Can you hint what's the issue?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/a8EKh9on7 - check this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that after the first read from the string stream, the stream will be at the "end of file". That is, `ss.eof()` will be true. It's not possible to read anything from the file.

This can be checked very easily with e.g.

```
if (!(ss >> std::hex >> output))
    std::cout << "Failed to read from the stream\n";
```

You "reset" the state of the stream first, to clear the state. For example with `ss.clear()`:

```
ss.clear();  // Clear the EOF state
ss << "0xAA";
ss >> std::hex >> output;
std::cout << output;
```

Comment: Note that the `eof` state results in a `fail` state at the *next* attempted read.  The `ss` itself is still in a `true` states (via `explicit operator bool()`), since that reflects the stream being in a `!fail` state.  When in a `eof && !fail` state, the stream is "primed" to fail in short order.